# What does "on the circuit" mean?

Tags: meaning

From the movie Choke (2008)
In the beginning the lead character is describing a group of sex addicts saying:

> They may not look like much to you, but they were all-stars on the
>   circuit.

Toward the end of the movie, the lead character has flashback about how he's became a sex addict. He remembered a woman in a plane's lavatory he accidentally saw naked and she made him to have sex with her saying

> There are no accidents on the circuit, honey.

I've read all vocabularies, but didn't find any definition that could explain what circiut they were talking about

I only can guess that it has something to do with sex addicts slang or something

Comment: In AmE slang, a circuit is the place where people engage in any habitual behavior. Here the circuit is the one where sex addicts go or hang out. It could be sports, politics, entertainment, whatever.

Comment: "On the circuit" is an idiom meaning something like "in the [specified field's] normal range of activities or venues." It derives (I believe)  from show business use, where "the circuit" was the normal series of cities or towns or clubs that a performer would visit when on tour. Lambie's comment with regard to the particular examples you ask about is very much on point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension of *[circuit](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=circuit)*, as AHD has it, in the sense of

> 4 a. A regular or accustomed course from place to place; a round:
>
> > a salesperson on the Detroit–Minneapolis–Chicago circuit;
> >      a popular speaker on the lecture circuit.

Roughly, the sex addicts will have relations any time they encounter one another, just as an author on a book tour might expect to visit every book store in an area, or a famous scholar might give lectures at a regular set of universities. Over time, because this is a limited community, the implication is that they will all have had sex with one another, as if according to a set itinerary or agenda.

I have not seen the film, but since it is a dark comedy, I would surmise this usage underscores that these liaisons are habitual and perfunctory, and not exciting or even enjoyable the way other people might envision them. This touches on the nature of addiction as something which destroys the pleasure in an otherwise pleasurable activity.